# How to interrupt a Future, but still wait for it to finish?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, future

I have series of jobs that I queue up using an ExecutorService. If the user clicks 'cancel', then I need to notify those jobs that they should stop as soon as possible. However, sometimes they are in critical sections of code that must complete before the parent thread should proceed. How can I do this? I don't want to use my own cancel flag, because that won't cause sleep/wait to exit.

I thought this code would work, but it doesn't do what I want:

```
while( true ) {
    //Do this in a loop. If our thread is interrupted, we call cancel on the threads (to try to get them to hurry up by skipping non-essential stuff), but we still need to wait for them to finish.
    try {
        for( Future<Void> future : futures ) {
            future.get(); //I thought that this would continue waiting, even if I call cancel, but it doesn't. How can I wait for the future to finish?
        }
        break; //OK, everything is finished, exit the wait loop.
    } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
        wasInterrupted = true; //We'll rethrow the exception laster as an AbortException.
        //Need to wait for futures to finish, even if it's canceled.
        log.info( "Attempting to interrupt threads that are reading changes..." );
        for( Future<Void> future : futures ) {
            future.cancel( true ); //I want to tell the threads to 'hurry up' and skip non-essential stuff.
        }
    } catch( ExecutionException e ) {
        throw e.getCause();
    }
}

//I shouldn't get to this line until all futures have finished!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to interrupt a Future, but still wait for it to finish?

Interesting problem.  Your code won't work because when you cancel a `Future`, as you have discovered, you cannot call `get()` again on it because that will throw a `CancellationException`.

If I am understanding your requirements:

- You need to be able to interrupt the threads because you want to stop `sleep`, `wait`, etc..
- You still want to be able to get the results of the tasks after they have been canceled.

On thing to do is to *not* use `Future`s here.  To instead use your own job wrappers and to wait for the `ExecutorService` itself to finish with `executorService.awaitTermination(...)`.

If you need the result of your tasks then your `Runnable` wrapper class would hold the result of the calculation and would have a `boolean done` flag.  The waiting thread would wait for each `Runnable` for their `done` flag to be set to true. When the wrapper finishes its `run()` method, it would set `done` and `notify()` on itself.  It would need to do that in a `finally` block.

If the waiting thread is interrupted, it would call `executorService.shutdownNow(true)` to interrupt all of the threads but would continue to loop waiting for them to finish.

Something like that.

Comment: That's a great solution. I did not know about the executorService.awaitTermination() method; that's exactly what I need.

Comment: However, I do not understand the part about using your own job wrappers. In my case, I don't need the result - I just need to wait for the threads to finish - so this doesn't affect me. But I'm curious how you can use an ExecutorService without using a Future object. Isn't that the only API for submitting tasks?

Comment: So if you don't need the result then it's a lot simpler.  If you call `submit(...)` then you get a `Future` but you can also call `execute(...)` which returns `void` and doesn't generate an internal `FutureTask` @JesseBarnum.

Comment: If you only need the thread to finish you don't need to do anything else: when you call cancel(true), the running thread will be interrupted. It's up to your code in the task to throw (by calling for example `sleep`) and catch the `InterruptedException` and take some sensible action, e.g., wait for the delicate operations to complete. Nothing new here.

Comment: Oh I should add that your task will run to completion (following the path that handles the `InterruptedException`) regardless of you calling `get()`.

Comment: PS: if the parent can't continue until some operation in the child is complete, you should use appropriate locks. It's cleaner.

Comment: Why is it cleaner @GiovanniBotta?  Why not let the `ExecutorService` so it for you?

Comment: What I mean is that the parent here has a dependency on the children. It's a different use case than a simple parent-child relationship so I thought it might be cleaner to model this dependency explicitly using one or more locks appropriately. Makes sense?

Comment: I don't see the need for that complexity @GiovanniBotta.  Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: Well in some cases `awaitTermination` can't be used, e.g., if the executor service is shared with other resources or if the service must be reused, i.e., `shutdown` hasn't been called (in which case `awaitTermination` will never return).

Comment: Gray, if you call execute(), which returns nothing, and then the user cancels the operation, what would you call interrupt on?

Comment: You would call `executorService.shutdownNow()` which interrupts the running threads @JesseBarnum.

Answer (score 0):

"as soon as possible" means that the thread should know when to exit

Anyway, you can use the Interrupt Thread policy

```
 if (Thread.interrupted())  // Clears interrupted status!
      throw new InterruptedException();
```

see also

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: The worker thread does know when to exit. The problem is that the parent thread doesn't know how long to wait, since Future.get() does not block once cancel has been called.